# String to replace in shell upto certain context

Tags: text-processing, sed, grep

I want to replace string in file using sed/grep but the string is mingled with another strings

Example:

```
sed -i 's/php/vinu/g' test.yml  # to replace string php with vinu
```

**test.yml**

```
php
phpehealth
dophp
testingphpin
```

In the above yml file contains multiple "php" strings, but I want to replace only "php" string with "vinu" and rest should not touch.

**expected o/p:**

```
vinu
phpehealth
dophp
testingphpin
```

Comment: Maybe because you are using the `/g` flag. Remove the /g flag and it will work beatifully for you. Also if your string always starts with `php` then consider `/^php/vinu/g'

Comment: What about `line with php inside`? Should the `php` get replaced here? (The given answers would do so) Or do you only want to replace a `php` in a line of it's own? (Then try `s/^php$/vinu/`)

Comment: Hi Philippos, I want to rename only php rather than other strings

Answer (score 0):

Use word boundaries in the regular expression if your version of sed supports them, e.g.

```
sed -i 's/\<php\>/vinu/g'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working.

Comment: I think the command should be sed -i 's/\<php\>/vinu/g'. You missed single quote before substitute

Comment: Note that this will only work with GNU `sed`

Answer (score 0):

Another way of word boundary :

```
sed -i 's/\bphp\b/vinu/g' file
```

Comment: Note that this will only work with GNU `sed`